Prioritization of data in SQL
I need to join the below 2 tables on Key. In the final table, I need Rank1 data in contact1 and if Rank1 is not there, I need to check next Rank. If Rank1 data comes to contact1, then I shouldn't consider Rank1 for contact2 and contact3. Is there a way to do in sql?
Table A:



Key1




1234


3456



Table B



Key2
Rank
contact




1234
1
owner


1234
2
co-owner


1234
3
CEO


3456
2
co-owner


3456
3
CEO



Final Table:



key
contact1
contact2
contact3




1234
owner
co-owner
CEO


3456
co-owner
CEO





Lookup using PIVOT. It's probably the tool you're looking for.

Always add a tag for the RDBMS you are using. From the sql tag wiki: "Questions should include .... a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) "

Seems like you'd need some dynamic pivot building here unless there are a definitive N number of contacts a Key can have. Does it max out at 3? 20? 1,000,000? Pivot requires you to know how many columns you need to have.

You can achieve the desired result using a combination of the ROW_NUMBER() function and conditional aggregation. Here’s a SQL query that accomplishes your goal:
WITH RankedContacts AS (
    SELECT 
        Key2 AS [Key],
        Contact,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Key2 ORDER BY Rank) AS RowNum
    FROM 
        TableB
)
SELECT 
    [Key],
    MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN Contact END) AS contact1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 2 THEN Contact END) AS contact2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 3 THEN Contact END) AS contact3
FROM 
    RankedContacts
GROUP BY 
    [Key];

This query first ranks the contacts based on their rank for each key. Then, it uses conditional aggregation to assign the appropriate contacts to contact1, contact2, and contact3.
A more extensive discussion of this issue can be found here: row number in sql server
